# Extending context_processor throughout app (blueprints included)

Tags: flask

I have a context processor within the main app

**app.py**

```
@app.context_processor
def context_processor():
    category_list = Category.list_names()
    return dict(category_list=category_list)
```

However, I am unable to extend this to the blueprints.

**views.py**

```
@categories_blueprint.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('base.jinja2.html', category_list=category_list)
```

I receive a Name error.

```
NameError
NameError: name 'category_list' is not defined
```

How would I be able to extend the argument across my entire Flask application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer, with help from u/dirn on reddit.

There is no need to pass the `category_list` argument again

The below would suffice.

```
@categories_blueprint.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('base.jinja2.html')
```